# How to Link to a Stylesheet in a subfolder

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, filepath

I have an HTML file, index.html, for my website, in a folder. This folder contains the index.html file, and another folder called "Stylesheets", with the stylesheet.css file inside. How do I link to it? I know how to do a link tag, but the href bit is giving me a bit of trouble. I've tried

```
href="../stylesheets/stylesheet.css"
```

and a few variants of it with the dots. Any ideas? I've tried a couple google searches but the question is a bit too complex to describe in a simple google query. Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path - `href="../stylesheets/stylesheet.css"` is basically doing the opposite of what you want.It's not going one folder further as you wish.

To accomplish what you want, you are going to have this path:

```
href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css"
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) you can read more about **File Paths**.

Answer (score 3):

Use `href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css"` or `href="./stylesheets/stylesheet.css"`
Both mean the look for stylesheet.css file inside the stylesheet folder inside the current folder.